# Crash in Unity 2018 4.13f1 EXC_BAD_ACCESS on GarbageCollectSharedAssets

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

I am getting a random crash on GarbageCollectSharedAssets. I am using unity 2018.4.13f1. Let me know if anyone else has faced this. This happens mostly during asset bundle loading. 
This doesn't seem like a memory issue.

Mentioning the full stack trace below.

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS Attempted to dereference garbage pointer 0x1. 
beta il2cpp::vm::LivenessState::AddProcessObject(Il2CppObject*, il2cpp::vm::LivenessState*)
beta il2cpp::vm::LivenessState::TraverseArray(Il2CppArray*, il2cpp::vm::LivenessState*)
beta il2cpp::vm::LivenessState::TraverseObjects()
beta il2cpp::vm::Liveness::FromStatics(void*)
beta GarbageCollectSharedAssets(bool, bool)
beta UnloadUnusedAssetsOperation::IntegrateMainThread()
beta PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingSingleStep(PreloadManager::UpdatePreloadingFlags, int)
beta PreloadManager::UpdatePreloading()
beta ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)
beta ExecutePlayerLoop(NativePlayerLoopSystem*)
beta PlayerLoop()
beta UnityPlayerLoopImpl(bool)
beta UnityRepaint
beta -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaint]
beta -[UnityAppController(Rendering) repaintDisplayLink]
Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore CA::Display::DisplayLink::dispatch_items(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long)
Frameworks/IOKit.framework/Versions/A/IOKit _IODispatchCalloutFromCFMessage
Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation ___CFMachPortPerform
Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation ___CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation ___CFRunLoopDoSource1
Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation ___CFRunLoopRun
Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation _CFRunLoopRunSpecific
PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices _GSEventRunModal
Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIKit _UIApplicationMain
beta main
/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib _start
```

Happens in iPhone 8 (device)
Incremental GC Not enabled (Using unity 2018)
Only happens with IL2CPP
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: I found a thread here, but unfortunately it doesn't address a definitive solution. By the way, maybe it could help you out: https://forum.unity.com/threads/ittermittent-crashes-on-ios-due-to-heap-corruption.487126/

Comment: Is this crash in the editor or in a build? On which OS does it happen? It seems like you are using il2cpp, does it also happen in Mono? Are you using the incremental GC experimental feature? if so does it happen without incremental GC (or with if not)?

Comment: @Remy I have added edits as a reply to your question

Comment: @GeoPaul Have you found the answer to this issue? or any lead on the same?
I'm facing a similar issue in Unity 2020.3.25, and targeting PC/Standalone (VR). Your suggestions might be really useful for me

Thanks in advance! :)